# Angular 4 war file not running on JBOSS

Tags: java, angular, jboss, http-status-code-404

I am new in angular and build a project with angular 4 as front end and JAVA Rest API as backend. I created a war file to deploy it on JBOSS but when I am trying to run the angular 4 war file on JBOSS but it gives me 404. It seems like some base-href issue in index.html. I tried with below base-href but nothing works:

```
<base href="/">
<base href="./">
<base href="/PROJECT_NAME/">
```

Please help me out in this.

[image: War File Structure]

Below is WEB.Xml for the same :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LeadAdminBackEnd</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.newgen.aproj2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restAPI/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

    <filter>
        <!-- The CORS filter with parameters -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <!-- Note: All parameters are options, if omitted the CORS 
             Filter will fall back to the respective default values.
          -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2,X-Requested-With</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
            <param-value>3600</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Make JAR not WAR ;)

Comment: Can you please explain the approach?